Disable specific Tkinter Button from an array of buttons when button is pressed
I have an array of buttons, that i would like to disable when pressed.   But no matter which button I press, the last button only gets disabled. anyone would be able to guide me with the right solution.
buttons_text_var = [StringVar() for i in range(25)]

def set_button_function(button_index):
    buttons[button_index].config(state="disabled")

buttons = [Button(window,textvariable = buttons_text_var[i],command=lambda : set_button_function(i), height=button_height, bd=button_border_size,
            font=(button_text_font, button_text_size), width=button_width) for i in range(25)]


If i press a specific button, i want it to be disabled. but only the last button gets disabled. no matter which button is pressed

For future questions, please provide a simple executable example. To recreate your function, other people would have to define variable such as the button_text_size, add all the tkinter boilerplate. Just create a simple example with that in already.

You'll need to modify the section with the lambda to use i=i
buttons = [Button(window,textvariable = buttons_text_var[i],command=lambda i=i : set_button_function(i), height=button_height, bd=button_border_size,
            font=(button_text_font, button_text_size), width=button_width) for i in range(25)]

Failing to do this means that the lamda function will always use the last value.

Great, thank you for your help Scotty. i=i, did the trick.
